# Creating graph of countries from 2D border image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, graph

I have a couple of 2D charts in either PNG, JPG or SVG format of connected countries, areas and cities in black and white. The borders are black, the rest is white. The maps are pretty plain; no icons, just borders.

I would like to programmatically create a graph of nodes representing the connecting countries. (Country A is connected to B and C, C is connected to A and D... etc). The names or labels of the countries are irrelevant and can be chosen arbitrarily.

How would I go around doing this? I guess that SVG would be easier, but most cases I am stuck with a 'flat' PNG or JPG.

Note that the maps are not always of real-world areas. It would not be possible to simply look up which countries are connected to which countries throug other sources.

**EDIT:** Added an example image of a world map. It is the closest I could find on short notice that somewhat resembles my problem:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZCIM.png

[image]

Comment: Can you post some examples? It is difficult to understand and that may  get your question closed.

Comment: Thanks Ander Biguri, added an example image.

Comment: In your images, is there water? or it is just a bunch of white areas with black borders?

Comment: You may want to look into the concept of a [*dual graph*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph) or alternatively: `bwconncomp`/`bwlabeln`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I tried. I'm focusing on a smaller region of the given image to easily illustrate the concept.

- extract the white regions
- label the extracted white regions
- dilate the labelled image with a sufficiently large kernel. A region with low label value will be populated with pixels of nearby high label value regions as a result
- for each label region, check the unique values in the corresponding dilated region. This will give you the region associations (edges)
- this way you'll build the associations incrementally. For example

  associations for label 1:   1  2  5  8  9
  says region 1 is linked with regions 2, 5, 8 and 9

  associations for label 2:   2  3  4  5
  says region 2 is linked with regions 3, 4 and 5 etc.

  ```
  im = imread('aus2.png');
  gr = rgb2gray(im);
  % get the white regions
  white = gr > 200;
  % label the image. you might have to erode the image before labelling
  % because even with 4-connectivity you might get merged regions
  lbl = bwlabel(white, 4);
  figure, imshow(label2rgb(lbl))
  % dilating the labeled image will propogate its maxima. 
  % a region with low label value will be populated with the nearby high
  % label values as a result of the dilation
  di = imdilate(lbl, ones(5));

  figure
  levels = unique(lbl);
  % skip the label value 0 as it is the background
  for i = levels(2):levels(end)
       subplot(1, levels(end), i), imshow(lbl == i), title(['label:' num2str(i)])
       % check each region for its unique values
       ['associations for label ' num2str(i) ':   ' num2str(unique(di(lbl == i))')]
  end
  ```

Input Image:

[image]

Labelled image (manually numbered):

[image]

Label regions:

[image]

Associations:

```
associations for label 1:   1  2  5  8  9
associations for label 2:   2  3  4  5
associations for label 3:   3  4  6
associations for label 4:   4  5  6  7  8
associations for label 5:   5  8
associations for label 6:   6  7
associations for label 7:   7  8
associations for label 8:   8  9
associations for label 9:   9
```